# Is there any way to change the default camera angle in Batman Arkhum Asylum?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

The default camera angle in Batman Arkhum Asylum is behind Batman and a little on his right. Due to this Batman appears on the left side of the screen which I don't like. I am quite used to having characters right in the center of the screen. Maybe I have this preference because it appears symmetrical and I'm used to this as a lot of games have it this way.

So my question is, is there any way I can change the camera angle in Batman? I looked at the controls but cannot find any way to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot manually change the standard camera angle in Batman Arkham Asylum.

Maybe that's the only flaw in the game. There are automatic camera adjustments during gameplay, and you can control the camera view with the right thumbstick.

Comment: The right thumbstick is where on a PC?  Oh, yes, there's a PC version.  The other answer has the same problem.

Comment: @jae: Calm down. It's probably the `Arrow Keys` on PC. I don't know for sure 'cause I didn't play it on PC.

Comment: well, actually its the mouse on the pc. Guess no one thought of that huh. :P I've finished the game by now and didn't find any other keys that change the camera angle.

Answer (score 2):

**Not permanently.**  You can move the camera using the right-stick on the PS3 (which I assume is the same on the XBox 360), but once you release, the camera goes back to its default angle.